# How can i use the "list" function and get all items in a single index on python?

Tags: python, list

So i'm working on this really long program, and i want it to save an input inside of a new list, for that i have tried doing:

```
thing=list(input("say something"))  #hello  
print(thing)  
#[h,e,l,l,o]
```

how can i arrange it to get `[hello]` instead?

Comment: Are those outputs actually `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']` and `'hello'` or something else such as `['hello']`?

Comment: No they really are 'hello' and [h,e,l,l,o]..

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
thing = [input("say something")]
```

In your version "hello" is treated as an iterable, which all Python strings are. A list then gets created with individual characters as items from that iterable (see [docs on `list()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)). If you want a list with the whole string as the only item, you have to do it using the square bracket syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I'd say the easiest would be to initialize `thing` with an empty list and then append the user's input to it:

```
thing = []
thing.append(input("say something: "))
```

Comment: It won't work in my case, i'm making a dictionnary that stores a name, and for each name assign a list containing the person's hobbies. ex: {ralf:['eating','drinking,'swimming'],jade:['smthg','smthg','smthg']}

Comment: @Badmephisto you can call `thing.append` multiple times. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Nevermind right now, it's been solved. Thanks anyways for the help :)

Comment: @Badmephisto if it solved your problem, please select this answer as the right one :)